# VSC extension Prettier doesn't format on save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I know there's a lot of duplicate questions, but generally the fix is to set Prettier as the default formatter. This is not the case here.

My Visual Studio Code settings are as follows:

```
// Settings.json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc.json",
  "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "prettier.requireConfig": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

My Prettier config is as follows:

```
// .prettierrc.json
{
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "noSemi": true
}
```

Prettier was working properly until yesterday. I disabled it, didn't touch settings, and enabled it again. Now, it's gone. I've tried tinkering with the settings quite a while with no success. Reinstalling the extension, reactivating the extension does not seem to have any result. AutoDelay is disable on autoSave, as well, since I know that Prettier has a problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't linking to my prettier config properly. All I needed to do is change

```
"prettier.configPath": "./web/proj/.prettierrc"
```

If anyone else is encountering this issue, beware prettierrc!